# Hint on how to loop while rendering in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, crud

I am new to Reactjs and trapped in this code,  I am able to render the data but its calling ProductItem component for each product

can anyone hint me with proper way to loop without calling ProductItem for each product

**App.js**

```
render() {     

 return (
         <div >   
           <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
                  <span className="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Product Manager</span>
            </nav>

                  { 
                    this.state.products.map(product => {
                      return (
                        <ProductItem
                           key={product.name}
                            {...product}
                        />
                      );
                    })   
                  } 
             </div>
                );
              }
```

**ProductItem.js**

```
class ProductItem extends Component {


 render(){
  const {name, price, quantity} = this.props;
         return(
             <div className="container">           
                    <table className="table table-striped">
                     <thead>
                       <tr>
                         <th>Product Name</th>
                         <th>Product Price</th> 
                         <th>Quantity </th>  
                       </tr>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody>
                     <tr>
                       <td>{name}</td>
                       <td>{price}</td>
                       <td>{quantity}</td>
                       <td><button className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
                   </tr>
                   </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
                );
            }
        }
```

Comment: Put table in App.js and loop `tr`s inside table body.

Comment: Don't put `<ProductItem />` in the loop? WIthout knowing what you *want* to do, other than "don't put `<ProductItem />` in the loop", it's difficult to know how to help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `<ProductItem />` in the loop. you passing `this.state.product` as a props of `<ProductItem />` Like:

```
<ProductItem products={this.state.product} />
```

Then your `<ProductItem />` component looping the like

```
this.props.products.map((product, index) => {
   <tr key={product.index}>
       <td>{product.name}</td>
       <td>{product.price}</td>
       <td>{product.quantity}</td>
       <td><button className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
   </tr>
})
```

inside the table tbody tag

Comment: @Abhishek, it's working or not? if works then accept the answer otherwise comments, whats not working? I will update my answer.

Comment: Well, actually he *should* put `<ProductItem>` into the loop. What he should do is to extract the `<table>`, `<thead>` and `<tbody`> elements to the `App` component. Or create a new component `ProductTable` which would contain `ProductItem` components.

Comment: I think he does not need another component `ProductTable` that you mentioned. also, he can reduce `ProductItem` component putting table inside the `App.js`. but his code scenarios say's he can pass product as a props and in `ProductItem` component he can loop inside the `table body`

Comment: I am creating new component just for table i.e ProductItem so as to keep my app.js clean

Comment: this isnt working, I am getting error here   > 
this.props.products.map(product => {

Comment: In your product array, `id` exist or not?

Comment: in `map` function must render a key property and it is unique. so what's value on your product should be that put on `key={product.yourUniqueChoice}` that's it.

Comment: If you have no unique value then modify your `map` function replace `product =>` with `(product, index) =>` then `key={product.index}`

Comment: this is my app.js   <ProductItem    {...this.props} />

Comment: this is my ProductItem.js                                                             <tbody>
                 {
             this.state.products.map(product => {
                 return(
                 <tr key={product.name}>
                   <td>{product.name}</td>
                   <td>{product.price}</td>
                   <td>{product.quantity}</td>
               <td><button className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
              </tr>
                 )
        })
    }
 </tbody>

Comment: app.js `<ProductItem products={this.state.product} />` see the answer again. i have made update with index key. just copy and paste on table boby tag

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined @   this.props.products.map((product, index) =>

Comment: add `constructor(props) { super(props); }` on your `ProductItem` component below the class declarations.

Comment: This below code works for me . Thanks                                                  <tbody>
              {       
          this.props.products.map((product) => {
            return (
                <tr key={product.name}>
                    <td>{product.name}</td>
                    <td>{product.price}</td>
                    <td>{product.quantity}</td>
                    <td><button className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            );
             })
            }
           </tbody>